# Getting an Assertion Error assert cookie_dict['sameSite'] in ['Strict', 'Lax'] while trying to set cookies for google login in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, setcookie

```
with Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get(notebooks[0])

    for cookie in pickle.load(open('cookies.pkl', 'rb')):
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

I dumped the cookies first by logging in manually, but getting this error while setting them.

Comment: just a pure guess here, but maybe you have to add each cookie while the browser is at the site it originated from?  Also note that any session cookie won't work here, because you have a new session.

Comment: @pcalkins yup, adding them exactly at the site where they originated from..

Comment: btw, this is to prevent other web sites from reading/writing those cookies.  (setting 'sameSite' attribute when setting the cookie...)  As you can see it won't prevent it when some sort of DOM injection occurs.  Something to consider when testing security... you may not be able to prevent this sort of thing, but you should make sure any value stored in a cookie cannot be used to takeover the account. (change e-mail, password, etc...)

Answer (score 8):

Found the answer to it!

Found out that google doesn't allow sending 'sameSite' cookie set to 'None'

Since 'sameSite' cookie was set to 'None' when I saved it from site, so sending it set to 'None' was against google's policy, resulting in assertion that it should be 'Strict' or 'Lax'

Here is the code that solved the problem

```
for cookie in pickle.load(open('cookies.pkl', 'rb')):
    if 'sameSite' in cookie:
        if cookie['sameSite'] == 'None':
            cookie['sameSite'] = 'Strict'
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```